# Multiple Github account in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, github, android-studio-3.0

I am working on different client projects and each will have different git user (username and password will be different). I am not able to find a way to save multiple git account against each project (multiple git clone urls). How can we configure multiple Github accounts in Android studio?

Comment: url will be different..

Comment: Thanks for your response :), That I understood. My question is, if we clone using different 2 remote urls (let say the saved git username and password is different for each project) and if we open two project at a time and try to pull the code the saved username and password will conflict. How we can save two git account details at time?

Answer (score 5):

To configure multiple GitHub accounts just follow the steps below:

Goto File -> Settings -> Version Control -> Github.

press Alt + insert to enter a new GitHub account to your android studio.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For each of your project : 
Set git remote url pointing to your specific github account
And when you push your commits just use account credential related to that git account

Comment: Thanks for your response :), That I understood. My question is, if we clone using different 2 remote urls (let say the saved git username and password is different for each project) and if we open two project at a time and try to pull the code the saved username and password will conflict. How we can save two git account details at time?